# What do you do to make positive you remember your water bottle?

Tags: commuter, hydration

I commute 11 miles to work, and at least once a month, at about mile 2, I'll look down and notice I left my water bottle on the counter at home!

What tricks do you have to make sure this doesn't happen to you?

Comment: Since there's different tricks and none is the one right answer, shouldn't this be a community wiki?

Comment: @freiheit, @M. Converse: Yes, I agree, this should be community wiki.

Comment: Is this relevant to this forum?  I see this more as a general topic of how to remember things.

Comment: @milesmeow: I think this is relevant, since the question is asking how to remember something ride-supporting (i.e., hydration mechanisms common to most bikes).

Comment: Seems relevant as I can see this possibly being something that would be bad news for a cyclist in general.  I question the commuter tag as *most* commutes are short enough that one doesn't usually need to carry water.  Unless I'm going 15+ miles or it's an extremely hot day, I don't bother to throw any water on the bike.  Especially not in a commuter type environment where I'm more likely to need to be continually dodging cars (and not have the time/opportunity to take a drink).

Comment: You can see your home's counter from Mile 2 of your commute?!

Comment: As [discussed on meta](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/635/76) this is a chatty forum-style question. Closing.

Answer (score 18):

I'm not a commuter, but I believe in putting something that must not be forgotten next to something that might be forgotten.

For instance, I would put my bike gloves on top of my water bottles.

(I do the same thing when I have people over to visit. If there's something in the fridge that I want them to take home, I put their car keys in the fridge on top of the container.)

Comment: Tried that - was late for work looking for my car keys.

Answer (score 13):

I leave anything I don't want to forget infront of the front door such that I cannot open it without knocking the thing over.

Answer (score 8):

I hang my helmet on the bottle cage. I almost always notice it's empty when I grab the helmet.

In the past I've stuck a sock monkey in the cage at the end of the ride. I thought I would always notice the sock monkey. But when you start out early in the morning sometimes you don't see things like that. I finally figured it out from the funny looks I was getting. So while thirsty, I still brought a smile to everyone on the route that morning.

Answer (score 6):

Mine stays on my bike all the time. After I clean/fill it, I put it back on my bike.

I do run the risk of forgetting to fill it up, but the worst that's happened so far is that I've ended up with half a bottle of day old water. Which is much better than no water :)

Answer (score 3):

You might get into the habit of inspecting your bike before you take off.  I check the tires and the brakes every time I pull the bike off its rack.  Check your cages along with it.

Mentally I classify water along with protective gear, probably giving it more weight than a helmet.  It isn't something that's merely nice to have because you're a little thirsty.  It's something that stops me from having a stroke in the heat (and cramps when I'm done).

Vaguely related.  I keep $2 on my bike so I can buy a bottle of water if I have to.

You could also place something in your cage that won't let you operate the bike after you get off it when you're done.  It's easy to remember your water bottle at the end, because you're thirsty.  Pick up the water bottle and place your pump or something in the cage so you have to pull it out and remember the water before you leave next time.

My advice though is to treat water with the importance is has.

Answer (score 2):

I use a camelbak - if I am planning on riding the next day, I will fill it up the night before and stick it in the fridge.  The camelbak is great, not just because you can take more water but you can also carry tools, extra tubes/patch kit, a pump...

Answer (score 2):

1. always having spare bottle is never hurt, making sure you'll have clean bottle whenever you needed one
2. i have developed habit to drink just before riding (always). even if not thirsty which mean i'll have to check my bottle, and if something wrong (like the bottle was empty) i still at home (office)

   - i'm using bicycle as my main method of transportation (whether its near or far)

Answer (score 2):

For me, I use a check list. It hasn't happened yet, but I fear the day I arrive at work having left some part of my work wardrobe at home.  Anyway, the list has everything I need, and I just run down it before heading out the door. Nerdy, maybe, I like to think it's cool like jet pilots.

Answer (score 1):

I fill mine up the night before and put them infront of the coffee cream. I always have coffee and when the bottles are in the way I just put them on the bike right away.

Answer (score 1):

1. I have two<sup>*</sup> bottle cages, both with a water bottle in them
2. I leave the bottles on the bike; refill the night before and put back on the bike when full.  (or fill when I get the bike to work or ...)

If I forget to refill, I have the other water bottle (and probably half of the first).  I also use decent quality water bottles that don't make the water taste too bad if it's sat in the bottle for a few days.

If for some reason I'm leaving the water bottles inside the house, I'll put them where they block access to something I can't leave the house without, such as putting one in each shoe.  (no, really)

<sup>*</sup> 3 bottle cages, actually, but one holds a travel mug that sometimes gets a hot beverage

Answer (score 1):

I use a visualization technique.  I visualize something I must do - mount the bike for example - and use that activity as a trigger to ask myself a question; do I have my water bottle, my pack, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I have a list stuck on the garage wall next to all my bike stuff. It really annoys me when I forget things so I always check it at least twice.

Answer (score 0):

I leave it on the bike, but I have the luxury of not leaving my bike outside.

Answer (score 0):

I carry my water bottle(s) with me if I'm going to be somewhere without convenient (or cheap) access to decent beverages for an extended period of time. This includes classes, driving for more than a few minutes in the car, movie theaters and fast food restaurants that charge $4 for a PET water bottle, etc.

I have been doing this regularly for about two years now, so anytime I leave home without a water bottle, I can't help but notice I'm forgetting something.

Answer (score 0):

I also commute 20 miles in a day. I have ran into your problem more than once. However I have a small trick to stay on safe side.

I have a back bag, which has separate pockets for water bottle on two sides. 
I have two bottles, One I always keep on the bag, and never take it off unless I am refilling my actual water bottle. Another I keep at the bike.

Whenever I get off the bike, i put that bottle on my bag, and when i am riding again, i put in back on the bike. This way, even if forget about the bottle, it will remain in my backpack, which I hardly forget.

In case I forget to refill, I will have a extra bottle, from which I can refill the bike. Or in the worst case, if i left/lost my bike's bottle somewhere I already have a bottle at my bag, which can handle the rest.